# Facebook share SDK not fetching image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to share a dynamic content to Facebook and below is my code, everything works fine but the image is not taking, no idea what is the issue is. Below is my code

FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: fb_share_url,
        picture: picture,
        quote: title,
    });

Comment: You have to put og:image tag on the URL.

Comment: I have tried that also

Comment: Which URL are you sharing? And what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

For fetching images i prefer Piccaso Open source library

Comment: please explain more this can be done using comment as well this is not an answer.